# (discord.js) Select specific channel in a guild

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need this to work but I don`t know what the variable selectedchannel to be. I need to delete all messages on 710069375184404500 channel. I am using ***v12*** Discord.js.

```
var selectedchannel =  .....

selectedchannel.messages.fetch({ limit: 99 }).then(messages => { 
     selectedchannel.bulkDelete(messages)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by getting the channel first.

```js
var selectedchannel = client.channels.cache.get('710069375184404500')

selectedchannel.messages.fetch({ limit: 99 }).then(messages => { 
     selectedchannel.bulkDelete(messages)
```